# Implementing multi list comprehensions in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

Im implementing a macro to do list comprehensions

```
(define-syntax list-comp
  (syntax-rules (for in if)
    [(list-comp <expr> for <var> in <list>)
     (map (lambda (<var>) <expr>) <list>)]
    [(list-comp <expr> for <var> in <list> if <cond>)
     (map (lambda (<var>) <expr>)
          (filter (lambda (<var>) <cond>) <list>))]))
```

I wanna modify this macro so it can accept any number of lists.

so for example
`(+ l1 l2) for in List1 List2` would return the sum of adding each element in each list
and should also work with `(+ l1 l2 l3...) for in list1 list2 list3` and so on...

Comment: Are you just doing this for fun? Racket comes with a [much more general comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) system, and there's no point for you to try to reimplement it.

Comment: Yep just trying to learn macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since map can map over several lists at once, the multi variable case is a natural extension of the one variable case.

```
(define-syntax list-comp
  (syntax-rules (for in if)
    [(list-comp <expr> for (<var> ...) in <list> ...) ; 
     (map (lambda (<var> ...) <expr>) <list> ...)]
    [(list-comp <expr> for <var> in <list>)
     (map (lambda (<var>) <expr>) <list>)]
    [(list-comp <expr> for <var> in <list> if <cond>)
     (map (lambda (<var>) <expr>)
          (filter (lambda (<var>) <cond>) <list>))]))

(define xs '( 1  2  3))
(define ys '(10 20 30))

(list-comp (+ x y) for (x y) in xs ys)
(list-comp x for x in xs)
```

If you want to read more on list comprehensions, I can recommend chapter 7 of the book "The Implementation of Functional languages". You can can read the chapter online here:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/PAGES/127.HTM

The syntax is different from Scheme, but the rewrite rules can be translated directly into syntax-rules macros.